# List of various slightly different generic objects

Tags: c#, generics

I am merging some code bases into one and am trying to figure out a clever way to merge some slightly different generic objects into a list that builds some of the UI for filtering.

I have many Manager objects that produce and manage ResultSets that are built on top of some of the application base classes.

Any ideas would be great.  I am trying not to refactor old deep code as much as possible.

CityManager is something like

```
   ImAFilterSetManager<ImAFilterSetBase<CityBase>>
```

and ChainManger is something like

```
   ImAFilterSetManager<ImAFilterSetBase<ChainBase>>
```

The Manager executes the Initialize and returns a ImAFilterSetBase and wires the handler.

Is there a way to cast to something like below?

```
ImAFilterSetManager<ImAFilterSetBase<object>>
```

Execution code

```
      List<object> filters = new List<object>() { 
                        new CityManager(),
                        new ChainManager(), }

        //(XXXX as  object fails)
        foreach (ImAFilterSetManager<ImAFilterSetBase<XXXX>> filter in filters) 
        {
               var newFilter = filter.Initialize(_Client);

               filter.OnResultsChanged += filterResults_Handler;
        }
```

It does seem if use dyanmic i can Initialize (or at least it compliles and runs, havent tried much else) but I'm a little worried that would be bad form or cause side effects.

```
foreach (dynamic filter in filters) 
{           
    var newFilter = filter.Initialize(_Client);
}
```

Interfaces for reference ( generic  I is a ImAFilterSetBase(CityBase) and generic C would be CityBase or ChainBase class )

```
public interface ImAFilterSetManager<I>
        {
                event EventHandler<ResultSetArgs> OnResultsChanged;

                I Initialize(IClient client);
        }

        public interface ImAFilterSetBase<C>
        {
                string FilterName { get; set; }

                List<C> Filter { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: There are some interesting things you can do with reflection to [determine generic types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you have CityBase and ChainBase implement a shared interface?  Your types could then be:
ImAFilterSetManager<ImAFilterSetBase<ISharedBase>>

Comment: @cunningdave, absolutly this would work, but I was trying to not change any of the <IShareBase> since I have very little control over them.  It might be the only answer though.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, `Generic<A>` and `Generic<B>` are not related, unless you make them related. Create another *non-generic* class (or interface) - `FilterSetManager`, and have all your `ImAFilterSetManager<T>` derive from that, or implement that.

Then you can have a `List<FilterSetManager>`.

Answer (score 0):

You may think in the [Liskov Substitution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703634/SOLID-architecture-principles-using-simple-Csharp) Principle (**SOLID**), so a good way is relate the objects via an interface:

```
//defines the contract
public interface IObjectBase {
    //add signatures
}

class CityBase : IObjectBase /*, IAnotherBaseA */ {
    //implementation
}

class ChainBase : IObjectBase /*, IAnotherBaseB */ {
    //implementation
}
```

Now we are going to create a constraint for the `ImAFilterSetBase` and rename it to `AFilterSetBase`

```
public abstract class AFilterSetBase<T> where T : IObjectBase /*, new() */ {
        public string FilterName { get; set; }
        public IList<T> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

I am going to redefine the interface `ImAFilterSetManager` and rename it to `IFilterSetManager`

```
public interface IFilterSetManager {
    event EventHandler<ResultSetArgs> OnResultsChanged;
    AFilterSetBase<IObjectBase> Initialize(IClient client);
}
```

Now we can create the classes that implements `IFilterSetManager`:

```
public class CityManager : IFilterSetManager {
    public AFilterSetBase<IObjectBase> Initialize(IClient client) {
        //TODO: implementation
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

//other classes that implements IFilterSetManager 
class ChainManager : IFilterSetManager {
    public AFilterSetBase<IObjectBase> Initialize(IClient client) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Finally, in the end-class we can create the list as follow:

```
static void Main() {
    IClient _client;
    //_client = new ...

    var filters = new List<IFilterSetManager>() {
        new CityManager(),
        new ChainManager()
    };

    foreach (var item in filters) {
        var newFilter = item.Initialize(_client);
    }
}
```

---

## IMPLEMENTATION

An example implementation for `CityManager` could be as follow:

```
class CityFilter : AFilterSetBase<IObjectBase> {
    public CityFilter(string filterName) {
        this.FilterName = filterName;
        this.Filters = new List<IObjectBase>();
    }
}

public class CityManager : IFilterSetManager {
    public AFilterSetBase<IObjectBase> Initialize(IClient client) {
        var item = new CityFilter("City Filters");
        item.Filters.Add(new CityBase());
        return item;
    }
}
```

And then we can test it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        IClient _client;
        _client = null;

        var filters = new List<IFilterSetManager>() {
            new CityManager(),
            new ChainManager()
        };

        foreach (var item in filters) {
            var newFilter = item.Initialize(_client);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Filter name: " + newFilter.FilterName);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Filters added: " + newFilter.Filters.Count);
        }

        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This will  work, but I was trying not to change  the lowest generic because I have the least control over them.  Nice answer!